# box-view , Uploading buffer getting error Unsupported document type

Tags: node.js, box-view-api

view to upload a Buffer to Box. But I have been receiving the following error :

```
{ message: 'Bad request',type: 'error',details: [ { message: 'Unsupported document type.' } ] }
```

my code is the following :

```
    var boxViewLib= require('box-view');
    var boxView =boxViewLib.createClient(process.env.BOX_KEY);

    var boxOptions = {
        params:{ name:'red.jpg'}       
        ,retry : true
    }
// the params.Body is a Buffer 
boxView.documents.uploadFile(params.Body, boxOptions, function(err, boxData) {
                                     console.log('Upload to Box View');
                                     console.log('Err '+ err);
                                     console.log( boxData);
});
```

response is :

```
Upload to Box View
Err Error: Bad request
{ message: 'Bad request',
  type: 'error',
  details: [ { message: 'Unsupported document type.' } ] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you actually trying to upload a JPEG image? The View API currently only supports documents and text files (see the full list here: https://developers.box.com/view/#filetypes).

Otherwise, your code looks fine.